# Proof by well ordering: Every positive integer greater than one can be factored as a product of primes.

Tags: proof-explanation

I am reading the book [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring17/mcs.pdf) and have reached the chapter **2.3 Factoring into Primes** where there is an explanation how Well Ordering can be used to prove the following:

> Theorem 2.3.1. Every positive integer greater than one can be factored as a product of primes.

Here is the excerpt of the proof:

> Let *C* be the set of all integers greater than one that cannot be
>   factored as a product of primes. We assume *C* is not empty and derive a
>   contradiction.
>   If *C* is not empty, there is a least element *n ∈ C* by
>   well ordering. The *n* can’t be prime, because a prime by itself is
>   considered a (length one) product of primes and no such products are
>   in *C*.
>   So *n* must be a product of two integers *a* and *b* where *1 < a; b <
>   n*. Since *a* and *b* are smaller than the smallest element in *C*, we know
>   that *a; b ∉ C*. In other words, *a* can be written as a product of primes
>   *p1p2...pk* and *b* as a product of primes *q1...ql*.
>   Therefore, *n =
>   p1....pkq1....ql* can be written as a product of primes, contradicting
>   the claim that *n ∈ C*. Our assumption that *C* is not empty must
>   therefore be false.

I've managed to understand the proof, but I'm stuck on the following statement:

> So *n* must be a product of two integers

Why is this a 'must'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $n$ is in $C$, it cannot be factored into a product of primes.  $n$ cannot itself be prime, otherwise it would have the trivial factorization.  Since $n$ is not prime, it has proper integer divisors.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is appallingly convoluted! Here's a formulation that cleanly distinguishes the conceptually important parts, and is furthermore *constructive*. Your question is indirectly answered by the key lemma.

**Lemma.** Given any number $n$, the smallest factor $p$ of $n$ such that $p>1$ is prime.

*Proof.* Given a number $n$, let $C$ be the set of factors $a$ of $n$ with $a>1$. Since any factor $a$ of $n$ satisfies $1\leq a\leq n$, if $n=1$ then $C$ is empty and the statement is vacuous.

Otherwise, if $1<n$, then $C$ is non-empty since $n$ is a factor of itself; hence by well-ordering $C$ has a least element $p$. Since $1<p$ by definition of $C$, to show that $p$ is prime it suffices to show that the only factor $a$ of $p$ such that $1<a$ is $a=p$. But if $a$ is factor of $p$ with $1<a\leq p$, we also have that $a$ is a factor of $n$ such that $1<a$ (since $a$ is a factor of $p$ which is a factor of $n$). This means $a$ is in $C$, and since $p$ is the least element of $C$ we must have $p\leq a$. But since $a\leq p$ already it follows that $p=a$.

**Proposition.** Any number $n>1$ has a prime factorization.

*Proof.* Let $C$ be the set of quotients of $n$ by products of primes, i.e. let $C$ consist of numbers $m$ such that $n=p_1\cdots p_k\cdot m$ for some sequence of (not necessarily distinct) primes $p_1,\dots,p_k$. The set $C$ is not empty when $n>1$ since by the lemma $n$ has a prime factor $p$ (given by the smallest factor $p$ of $n$ such that $p>1$), in which case the quotient $m$ in $n=pm$ is an element of $C$.

It follows by well-ordering that $C$ has a minimal element $m$ so that $n=p_1\cdots p_k\cdot m$ for sequence of (not necessarily distinct) primes $p_1,\dots,p_k$. If $m>1$, then by the lemma $m=pq$ for some prime $p$, hence $n=p_1\cdots p_k\cdot p\cdot q$ implies $q$ is in $C$. But $1\leq q<m$ since $q$ is a quotient of $m$, which contradicts $m$ being minimal in $C$. Therefore, it cannot be the case that $m>1$, so we must have $m=1$. This shows that $n=p_1\cdots p_k$ for some sequence of primes $p_1,\dots,p_k$. Furthermore, the sequence may be constructed by successively taking smallest factors $p$ such that $p>1$.

Comment: I did not understand your lema: Given any number nn, the smallest factor pp of nn such that p>1p>1 is prime.
This sentence seems to be missing something for it to be understandable in english.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is not prime so it factors as $n=ab$ where $1<a;b<n$ and since $n$ was the smallest element of $C$ , $a$ and $ b$ are not in $C$ so they factor as product of primes.